# Forcing a namespace in root element when calling a SOAP ASMX web service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asmx, xml-namespaces

I have a .NET client calling into a SOAP .asmx web service. The client I'm developing is itself a WCF service under .NET 4. The destination .asmx web service is a Service Reference in the application. I don't have any control over the destination.

The problem is that when calling a web service, the XML that is created for the call doesn't include a particular namespace in the **root element** of the serialized XML of the proxy classes being sent.

Rather, it applies the namespace for a handful of elements nested within the document.

When using the proxy classes:

```
 var x = new RemoteService_PortTypeClient();
 x.SomeMethod(somePayload);
```

The destination service returns an exception when formatted with the hl7 namespace throughout:

> Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:hl7-org:v3:typeId'.

The current serialized proxy object (`somePayload`) is being sent as:

```
<MyRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    ....
    <MyNode value="20120801100803" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" />
```

How I'd like it to be sent:

```
<MyRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    ....
    <MyNode value="20120801100803"  />
```

How can I force my client to declare the namespace in the root, rather than being scattered in the element?

I know that having this namespace in the root will be accepted without error by the service, as it's been demonstrated to work in that way.

Are there declarations/attributes in `References.cs` or web.config or other to force this?

Comment: there is a class `XmlSerializerNamespaces` which serializer's take. you can add this there.

Comment: @Ankush I'm speaking of the proxy classes that are created in the Service Reference. No explicit serialization is being done here.

Comment: yes I understand that. but the `svcutil.exe` or whatever is generating the proxy class usually take some console args, maybe there lies the answer. I'm just guiding u, I don't know the answer.

Comment: This is not your problem. Neither WCF nor ASMX cares where namespaces are declared, as long as they're declared correctly, and in time. There is no difference between the two examples of `MyNode`.

Comment: Well it may be valid XML and syntactically correct, but a number of Java servers apparently don't work with inline namespace declarations. I'm working with a big English Mail service and I just ran into this same issue - it's lame, but it doesn't help to know I'm right and their server sucks :-) In the end I have to build the messages so the server accepts them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue by creating a Web Reference instead of a Service Reference.

[image]